# I can't local streaming in a fragment android

Tags: android, stream

I'm having a problem streaming to an Android device in a fragment but everything works fine in a normal actionbar but when I implement the code in a fragment, the video can't play, knowing that I tried a normal url and it worked only the local rtsp doesn't
here is the code I'm using

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);


    final VideoView vidView = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(getActivity());
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    String vidAddress = "rtsp://192.168.1.67:8080/test.mp4";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Where do you start the video?

Comment: I tried with the command vidView.start() and starting it manually but it doesn't work